# Unexpected type inference failure: wrong number of type arguments

Tags: rust, type-inference, generic-programming

In this example, the compiler can not infer the matrix type:

```
type Mat4x4<T> = [T; 16];

fn main() {
    let m: Mat4x4 = [0.4323f32; 16];
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

The working code is:

```
type Mat4x4<T> = [T; 16];

fn main() {
    let m: Mat4x4<f32> = [0.4323f32; 16];
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

Is this an expected act?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a type inference issue:

```
type Mat4x4<T> = [T; 16];

fn main() {
    let m: Mat4x4 = [0.4323f32; 16];
    println!("{:?}", m);
}
```

Yields the following error message:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     let m: Mat4x4 = [0.4323f32; 16];
  |            ^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

The complaint here is that `Mat4x4` is not a type, it's a *template* or *blueprint* to create a type.

An analogy would be that `Mat4x4` is a waffle iron, and `Mat4x4<f32>` is a waffle that comes out of it. If you are served the waffle iron (with maple syrup on top, of course) you will likely be disappointed!

The same applies here: when you give the compiler the blueprint where it expects the final product, it signals you that it was not what it expected.

---

You can supply a dummy argument (`_`), and it will be inferred:

```
let m: Mat4x4<_> = [0.4323f32; 16];
```

Comment: I liked your waffle example. :D

Answer (score 4):

You cannot omit required type parameters, but you can use `_` to infer them:

```
let m: Mat4x4<_> = [0.4323f32; 16];
```

Alternatively, you could add a default type parameter so you could omit the `<…>` when the type `T` is exactly `f32` (but this is not type inference, you still need to write `Mat4x4<f64>` explicitly).

```
type Mat4x4<T = f32> = [T; 16];
```

```
let m: Mat4x4 = [0.4323f32; 16];
```

Comment: In most of the times you don't need to use '_' for inferencing, is this something expected in here?

Comment: @HosseinNoroozpour: You mean when you infer the whole type, e.g. `let m = [0.4f32; 16];`? But here you are restricting it to a `Mat4x4<T>`.